# SQL query in Oracle and SQL server to get 3rd highest salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

In oracle will the below query works for getting 3rd highest salary.

```
select empname, salary 
from (select empname,salary from employee order by salary desc) 
where rownum==3
```

I have seen answers in other threads but they seem to be complicated. If above query works then it is simple solution for oracle

What will be the  query for SQLServer?

I don't have Oracle and SQLServer software to try out these queries.

Please let me know

Comment: The equality operator in SQL is `=`, not `==`. To test your queries you can use: http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some exploration and found below link which explains the difference between `row_number()`, `rank()` and `dense_rank()`. From the below link I found `dense_rank()` is suitable answer for this question.

http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/tutorial/24-interview-questions/190-top-20-sql-interview-questions-with-answers.html

`row_number()` does not give expected results if two or more empolyees has same salary.

Below query works for both Oracle and SQL Server when tried on http://sqlfiddle.com/. The following query gives you the list of employees with third highest salary

```
SELECT empname, salary FROM (SELECT empname, salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) dense_rank_by_sal
FROM EMPLOYEE ) A  where dense_rank_by_sal=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dense_Rank()` ranking function in `SQL SERVER` to find the 3rd highest salary.

`Row_number()` returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.The `ORDER BY` clause determines the sequence in which the rows are assigned their unique `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT empname, 
       salary 
FROM   (SELECT Dense_Rank() OVER(ORDER BY salary DESC) rn, 
               empname, 
               salary 
        FROM   employee) A 
WHERE  rn = 3
```

Comment: This will work in Oracle as well. Window functions are nothing special to SQL Server (in fact Oracle had them ages before SQL Server)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Pradeep -- you mean that this does not work or not reliable for oracle

 "select empname, salary 
from (select empname,salary from employee order by salary desc) 
where rownum==3 "

 and that "SELECT empname, 
       salary 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY salary DESC) rn, 
               empname, 
               salary 
        FROM   employee) A 
WHERE  rn = 3 "
  works for both Oracle and SQLServer and reliable ..ryt

Comment: @ChaitanyaK - Yes == wont work in ORACLE or SQL SERVER and my code will work in both sql server and oracle.

Comment: @pradeep -- Thanks for your answers. I was not asking about ==..Anyway let say i replaced == with = then will it give expected results in Orcale i.e 3rd higest salary.

 "select empname, salary from (select empname,salary from employee order by salary desc) where rownum=3 "

Comment: @pradeep - Your query does not work as expected if two or more employees has same salary.

I found below link

Comment: @ChaitanyaK In that case you need to use `Dense_Rank()`

Comment: @pradeep - Your query does not work as expected if two or more employees has same salary.

I found below link which explains the difference bteween row_number() and dense_rank. and found dense_rank() is suitable in case of multiple employee with same salary.
http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/tutorial/24-interview-questions/190-top-20-sql-interview-questions-with-answers.html

Comment: @ChaitanyaK - you have to mention that in your question. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server the solution would be like this:

```
Select TOP 1 Salary as '3rd Highest Salary'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Salary from Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC)
a ORDER BY Salary ASC
```